# Sending information when sharing on FB and FB OG , through URL using $_GET not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I created a code that gets information from an API and displays it dynamically.

```
   foreach($filtered_listings as $listing){
     get_template_part( 'template-parts/listings/img/image','cover', $listing); 
   }
```

Inside that template part i create the link this way

```
<?php //Get all variables from arrays present in passed args ?> 
<?php extract($args); ?>
<a class="img-frame listings-img-frame" href="'.$home_url.'/annonce?annonceId='.$info['id'].'">
```

So when I am in the page I get the ID of the specific page through $_GET, and diplay the right info.

```
  // filter_by_id is Declared in Functions.php
  $listing = array_filter($listings, "filter_by_id");
  $listing_key= key($listing);
  $this_listing= $listing[key($listing)];
```

So all of this is working fine and in my variable $this_listing I have the right info and can display it the right way.

NOW! I am trying to implement some FB crawlers in my function.php file

```
function insert_fb_in_head() {
  global $post;
  // Import api data from correspondent file and set variables that will be used and retreived
  include_once "api/api-setup.php";
  global $listings;
  global $token; 

  function filter_by_id($listing) { 
    global $annonceId;
    $annonceId = $_GET['annonceId'];
    return $listing['info']['id'] == $annonceId;
  }
  $listing = array_filter($listings, "filter_by_id");
  $listing_key= key($listing);
  $this_listing= $listing[key($listing)];

  extract($this_listing);
  
  if ( !is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
    return;
    echo '<meta property="fb:app_id" content="Your Facebook App ID" />';
    echo '<meta property="og:title" content="'.$info['titre'].'"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:description" content="blablabla"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="site Name"/>';
  if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
    $default_image="http://example.com/image.jpg"; //replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
    echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
  }
  else{
    $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
    echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
  }
  echo "
  ";
  }
  add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
```

This works properly on my website. If I var_dump($this_listing) or the only extracted variable I am using for now for instance $info['titre'] I have the desired information coming up.

BUT! when I share the url this way of fetching the proper listing id:

```
    $annonceId;
    $annonceId = $_GET['annonceId'];
```

returns an error of undefined variable.

Notice: Undefined index: annonceId in /var/www/vhosts/wapinails.be/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 64 Notice: Undefined index: annonceId in /var/www/vhosts/wapinails.be/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 64 Notice: Undefined index: annonceId in /v...

So I get that $_GET is not the right way to go in this case. Any suggestion on how to tackle this ?

Comment: Facebook considers what you specify as `og:url` to be the “real” URL of this piece of content, so it will explicitly fetch that to scrape the relevant data. So the URL you give in there, must include your parameters.

Comment: thank you, I have tried like this: `echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '/?annonceId='.$_GET["annonceId"].'"/>'; ` but sill not working ..

Comment: Did you re-scrape the URL using Facebook’s debug tool, to clear their cache?

Comment: Yes I do re-scrape every time I try a new solution.

Comment: Then give an actual example URL please, so we can check.

Comment: [link] https://wapinails.be/annonce/?annonceId=191

Comment: Debug tool say it is using the URL specified via the rel=cononical meta tag. It _should_ prioritize `og:url` though. But it also claims that that one is missing, together with several other og tags. That URL is still outputting a lot of undefined index notices, before the meta tags even come - so that’s a possible reason the debug tool is not able to read them correctly, so fix those notices first of all.

Comment: Ok Fixed, I played too much around and broke some things. and well it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Now though it blocks at the image property...                                                    `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxx" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo get_permalink().'?annonceId='.urldecode($_GET['annonceId']); ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $photos['1']['url']; ?>" />;
 <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $info['titre']; ?>"/><meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Découvrez cette annonce sur nontre site!"/>;
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="Ombri Immo"/>;`

Comment: going like this displays the image but breaks everything after: If I put the image last.... everything works except the image is there a specific order to follow?

Comment: According to the “exactly what our scraper sees” link at the bottom, those appear not to be present in the actual source code Facebook receives - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwapinails.be%2Fannonce%2F%3FannonceId%3D191

Comment: Ok SOLVED too I had `;`  after some meta tags and that broke it. Thanks again for help!!